# Factory method of IntBuffer (and other primitive type buffers) return instance but those classes are actually defined abstract

Tags: java, abstract-class, factory-method

```
abstract class IntBuffer
```

seems like you can't create an instance of this class anyway , because its declared abstract but at the same time , there's a static factory method 
`IntBuffer allocate(int capacity)` and now you can create an instance by simply `Buffer b=IntBuffer.allocate(128)` 
but wait, IntBuffer was abstract and it doesn't have any predefined concrete subclass . so how does this work ?

EDIT -------------

I already suspected its returning a subclass of IntBuffer but hey I couldn't find HeapIntBuffer or any such subclass. Is it privately declared, I guess ?? hence its absence from api doc !

Comment: `IntBuffer.allocate(128)` returns a `new HeapIntBuffer(128, 128);` which is a conrete class...

Comment: I couldn't find this class anywhere in java api doc !

Comment: It's not public and its detailed implementation does not matter - it extends the `IntBuffer` class and that's all you need to know!

Comment: That's the beauty of it. It's an implementation detail transparent to you. Tomorrow the developer of IntBuffer could decide that it would be an improvement to return a different subclass. Your code would continue to work perfectly despite the change.  On the other hand, if the HeapIntBuffer was exposed and you downcasted and use it directly, a change to the implementation could break your code.

Comment: Yes I see . Its the same reason we use `List` variable to store `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because there's a static method there doesn't mean it's creating an instance of *just* `IntBuffer`. Here's a short example of the kind of thing a factory method can do:

```
abstract class Abstract {
   static Abstract createInstance(int size) {
       return size < 10 ? new SmallImplementation() : new LargeImplementation();
   }

   public abstract String getDescription();
}

class SmallImplementation extends Abstract {
   @Override public String getDescription() {
       return "I'm an implementation for small sizes";
   }
}

class LargeImplementation extends Abstract {
   @Override public String getDescription() {
       return "I'm an implementation for large sizes";
   }
}

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       Abstract small = Abstract.createInstance(1);
       Abstract large = Abstract.createInstance(100);
       System.out.println(small.getDescription());
       System.out.println(large.getDescription());
   }
}
```

This is basically at the heart of polymorphism - the code in `Test.main` *only* knows about `Abstract`; it's up to the factory method to choose the right implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It works because allocate doesn't return an IntBuffer, but a sublcass of IntBuffer.  Here is the source code for IntBuffer.allocate:

```
public static IntBuffer allocate(int capacity) {
    if (capacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return new HeapIntBuffer(capacity, capacity);
}
```

Class HeapIntBuffer extends IntBuffer, so when you say in your code:

```
IntBuffer myBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(size);
```

the assignment is fine.